# Trying to get property 'unit_price' of non-object but when I debug the results appear

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an error when I want to update the data I took from calling the field from the object that was already queryed when I debug using the ff results appear but when I input the variable when I want to update 'unit_price'=>$unit_price has appeared error Trying to get property 'unit_price' of non-object"

code

```
$pr_dtl = \DB::table('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
            ->get();
          
            foreach ($pr_dtl as $detail) {
                $qty_pr = \DB::table('pur_tra_purchase_request_outstanding_pr')
                ->where('pr_id',"<>" ,$request->transaction_id)
                ->where('status',DB::raw("4"))
                ->where('item_id',"=",$detail->item_id)
                ->sum('quantity');
                
                $qty_po = \DB::table('pur_tra_purchase_request_outstanding_pr_po')
                 ->where('item_id',"=",$detail->item_id)
                ->get();
                
                $unit= \DB::table('pur_tra_purchase_request_outstanding_pr_po')
                 ->where('item_id',"=",$detail->item_id)
                  ->orderBy('unit_price','desc')->limit(1)
                  ->first();

                $sum = $qty_po->sum('total_po');
              
                $hasil = $qty_pr-$sum;
                
                $unit_price=$unit->unit_price;
                ff($unit_price);
                \DB::table('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
                ->where('id', $detail->id)->update([
                    'qty_outstanding_pr'=> $hasil,
                    'unit_price'=> $unit_price
                ]);  
            }
          
            $this->where('id',$request->transaction_id)->update([
              'status'=>4,
            ]);
```

Comment: `first()` can return `null`, meaning the query did not have any result ... you need to check for this

Comment: but when am debug with  ff($unit_price); result is appear in console

Comment: you are doing this in a loop, so in one of the iterations `first` is returning `null` for the query you are running ...

Comment: so i must remove first and change get()?

Comment: you need to actually check if it returns something besides `null` before trying to use what is returned ... you have to decide what to do if there is no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take care of the null when it return from (first()) method:

```
 $unit= \DB::table('pur_tra_purchase_request_outstanding_pr_po')
                 ->where('item_id',"=",$detail->item_id)
                  ->orderBy('unit_price','desc')
                  ->first();
    if($unit!=null)
    {
      $sum = $qty_po->sum('total_po');
      $hasil = $qty_pr-$sum;
      $unit_price=$unit->unit_price;ff($unit_price);
      \DB::table('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
      ->where('id', $detail->id)->update([
     'qty_outstanding_pr'=> $hasil,
     'unit_price'=> $unit_price
    ]);  
}
```